# How to enable Loopback Access for a particular user using iptables in Ubuntu

Tags: iptables

I have disabled full network access to one of the users using following command

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p all -m owner --uid-owner foo -j DROP
```

This disabled everything for the user foo, but I want to allow Loopback Access, I have tried the following command

```
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -m owner --uid-owner foo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -m owner --uid-owner foo -j ACCEPT
```

But it's giving me `` iptables: Invalid argument. Run `dmesg' for more information. ``